# Did I do my work correctly for finding the recurrence equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The equation in question: $2y''-xy=0$ near $x_0=1$
First of all, I assume
 $y(x)$=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-1)^n$

Differentiating this gives us $y''(x)$=$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n(n)(n-1)(x-1)^{n-2}$

Plugging this in, I get: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2a_n(n)(n-1)(x-1)^{n-2}$ $-x$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-1)^n$$=0$

I rewrote this as: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)(x-1)^{n}$ $-(x-1+1)$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-1)^n$$=0$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)(x-1)^{n}$ $-$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-1)^{n+1}$$-$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-1)^n$$=0$

Changing the indices and seeing that both the first and third sums have a constant term for their respective $n=0$ term:

$2a_2-a_0
+$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)(x-1)^{n}$ $-$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}(x-1)^{n}$$-$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(x-1)^n$$=0$

Now all of the sums have $(x-1)$ to the same power and have matching indices.

$2a_2-a_0
+$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)-a_{n-1}-a_n)(x-1)^n$$=0$

From this, we get
$2a_2=a_0$ and $2a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)-a_{n-1}-a_n=0$

Thus, getting us a recurrence equation: $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)(2)}$

I'm just not sure if my work is correct so far. As always, thank you for your time.

Comment: In the fifth line, when $x=1$  we have $4a_2-a_0=0$. When $x=1$ all of the terms  of the 1st summation of the fifth line vanish except the term with $n=0$, which is $2a_{0+0}(0+2)(0+1)=4a_2$.